# More colors in my Python Altair Chart. Wider spectrum of colors

Tags: python, charts, colors, altair

Good morning. I have the following image:
[image: Click here to see the chart]

for the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_folder,"file.csv"))

chart = alt.Chart(data.reset_index(),title="Visualisation").mark_point().encode(
    x ="x",
    y ="y",
    color = 'id_species'
).encode(tooltip=['x','y','id_species'])

chart.encoding.x.title = 'first parameter'
chart.encoding.y.title = 'second parameter'

chart.show()
```

How can I do if I want the colors to go from let's say purple to green? If I want a wider spectrum of colors instead of shades of blue?*

[image: Something like that] (I did it with matplotlib but I would like to have it with Altair.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page from the altair documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#customizing-colors) describes how you can change color schemes. For example:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color=alt.Color('species', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='dark2'))
)
```

The color scheme you want is called `'viridis'` in altair, just as in matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly the right answer. Have a nice day !